# Jquery Animation Troubles

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I'm having difficulty with a jquery animation. When the image slider selects the next image, I want the previous one to slide down underneath it (while still remaining somewhat visible) Can someone fix this? Is it a jquery problem or CSS.

For simplicity (and failure at knowing how to organize my code here) here's the URL to edit: 
[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ixoqu3/3)

Thanks in advance

Comment: On your link, the _styles.css_ and the _bg.jpg_ can't load.

Comment: For the purposes of fixing this I don't need them to load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if it's what you mean by "still remaining somewhat visible", but check my modification http://jsbin.com/ixoqu3/5

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: Try to play with slideDown() or slideUp() from jQuery.